# How can I figure out what size shipping box I need based on multiple different smaller boxes?

Tags: optimization, volume, packing-problem

Is there a math formula I can use to provide a guideline of what **length x width x height** box I would need to buy based on smaller individual boxes that I want to put inside this larger box?

For example, if I have the following box dimensions; what large box size would I need to buy to fit these packages inside it?

- Box # 1: 15 x 10 x 5
- Box # 2: 10 x  8 x 3
- Box # 3:  5 x  3 x 2
- Box # 4: 11 x  9 x 8

Answer (score 4):

In general, this problem is very hard. See for example [this paper](http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/opre.48.2.256.12386?journalCode=opre). For the particular example you quote, an informal approach using common sense and trial-and-error is as good as any.